# Tablesorter, sub group sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I've tried to make a widget that can sort a group of rows separately inside a table and at the same time make the row-group to stick with "grouped rows". I can't figure out how to approach this problem ...

EDIT: I want to sort on the non colspan columns. every group should behave as a sub-table

Basic setup in jsfiddle, can anyone push me in the right direction ?

EDIT: new jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L8bwW/28/

Comment: How do you WANT to do your sorting? Do you want it to sort on wide rows, then on split rows, like the Finder/Explorer sorting alphabetically on folders and then on subfolders?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I want to sort on the non colspan columns.

every group should behave as a sub-table

Comment: So are the wide (colspan) rows attached to the single row below them? Or are they "fixed in place" and, for instance, appear as the third and sixth row regardless of how the others are sorted?

Comment: The colspan row is attached to the rows above it and it's not repeated every x index. Updated jsfiddle example

Comment: Okay, I think I see -- you want the groups to stay in place, but you want to sort the sub-groups between each wide (colspan) row. Yes?

Comment: This is complicated, but if you want to use the TableSorter plugin, you could try using nested sub-tables for each group and somehow use jQuery to slave each sub-table to the main headers.

Comment: nested tables is an option I've considered, the html-code gets really blotted, but it's better than blotted jQuery-code

Comment: @soderslatt let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2734/discussion-between-mblase75-and-soderslatt)

Comment: Just to let you know, I've updated my fork of tablesorter to now sort a table with multiple tbodies. Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WpSV4/) that does not use tablesorter.

The key is to use the `tbody` element to group your rows.  Then sort all rows but the last, within each tbody.

The table might look like this:

```
  <table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th></th> <th>A-head</th> <th>B-head</th> <th>C-head</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr> <td></td> <td>A-foot</td> <td>B-foot</td> <td>C-foot</td></tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody class='sortable'>
        <tr> <td>DDD</td><td> r1c1</td> <td>r1c2</td> <td>r1c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>AAA</td><td> r2c1</td> <td>r2c2</td> <td>r2c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>CCC</td><td> r3c1</td> <td>r3c2</td> <td>r3c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>BBB</td><td> r4c1</td> <td>r4c2</td> <td>r4c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td colspan="4">summary info for the first group of rows</td> </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody class='sortable'>
        <tr> <td>Zorro</td><td> r5c1</td> <td>r5c2</td> <td>r5c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>Caleb</td><td> r6c1</td> <td>r6c2</td> <td>r6c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>Momo</td><td> r7c1</td> <td>r7c2</td> <td>r7c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>Wolfie</td><td> r8c1</td> <td>r8c2</td> <td>r8c3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td colspan="4">summary info for rowgroup #2</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
     ...
```

And a sort fn for it might look like this:

```
  function SortIt() {
      jQuery('table.sortable > tbody.sortable').each(function(index,tbody) {
        var $rowGroup = jQuery(tbody);

        // select all but the last row in the tbody
        var rows = $rowGroup.find('tr:not(last-child)').get();

        var sortDirection = $rowGroup.is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;

        // Set a custom property on each row - 'sortKey', the key to sort.
        // This example uses the text in the first column. It could use
        // any column, or any content in the row.
        jQuery.each(rows, function(index, row) {
            row.sortKey = jQuery(row).children('td').first().text();
        });

        // actually sort the rows
        rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) return -sortDirection;
            if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) return sortDirection;
            return 0;
        });

        // retain the summary row - the last one
        var summaryRow = $rowGroup.find("tr:last-child");

        // remove all the rows from the tbody
        $rowGroup.find("tr").remove();

        // append the rows in sorted order
        jQuery.each(rows, function(index, row) {
            $rowGroup.append(row);
            row.sortKey = null;
        });

        // append the final row
        $rowGroup.append(summaryRow);

        if (sortDirection == 1) { $rowGroup.addClass('sorted-asc'); }
        else {$rowGroup.removeClass('sorted-asc'); }

      });
  }
```