# Javascript sort non-linear table

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I have table like that :

```
<table id="table_id" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr class="trheader">
<th colspan="2">111</th>
<th>-SORT-ME-</th>
<th>222</th>
<th>333</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="id_1"><img src=""></td>
<td id="id_11">11</td>
<td id="id_12">===SORT.VALUE===</td>
<td id="id_13">13</td>
<td id="id_14"><a href="#" class="send_data"><img src=""></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="id_t1" colspan="5" onclick="some_func">
<label for="id_i1">_lbl_</label>
<img id="image_1" src=""></img>
<div id="id_i1">
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="id_2"><img src=""></td>
<td id="id_21">21</td>
<td id="id_22">===SORT.VALUE===</td>
<td id="id_23"></td>
<td id="id_ordbtn_2"><a href="#"><img src=""></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="id_t2" colspan="5" onclick="some_func">
<label for="id_i2">_label2_</label>
<img id="image_2" src="">
<div id="id_i2">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
... more of the same...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is it somehow possible to use JQuery tablesorter or other script to sort the table based on values in -SORT-ME- // ===SORT.VALUE=== // ===SORT.VALUE=== and to keep the table displayed properly, as i tried to use tablesort(er) and it messes it ( start do switch rows... displays the table broken ) It's because of the second  :: colspan=5 data, that makes the table non uniform or non-standard or i don't know the exact phrase for that, i hope you get what i'm trying to say.

Sorry for the not very informative description of the problem, but as you've already guessed English is not my native language and i struggle when i need to explain more complicated things.

Thank you guys, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does each colspan 5 item create another group that needs sorted?  Also, can you modify how the table is in the HTML?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148436/tablesorter-sub-group-sorting/7149515#7149515) will help you.

Comment: I can change the table as long as it shows the data in similar way, the colspan=5 <tr> can not go on the same row as it contains long text so, i guess i can put it all in another row with hidden value taken from id_12/22 and try sorting that way.. will that work? I was hoping that someone had such problem in the past and knows how to deal with it. 10x fudgey for the example. I am open for ideas and modifications. 10x guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add a child row that gets sorted along with the parent row?

If so, I found [this demo](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm) on doing just that. It is actually part of the tablesorter plugin v2.0.5 but it isn't documented. So you can just copy the html and code they use, but you don't need to download the mod.

I've added the [missing documentation](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#cssChildRow) in a blog post I made and I've forked and modified the plugin itself on [github](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) and made another [child row demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html), if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you so much Fudgey, this will work perfectly. Many, many thanks and your blog is full of cool stuff. Billion sincere thanks!